# Where to place the close button in Dialog?

Tags: gui-design, ux-designer, modal-windows, visual-design

In my project I have placed the close button in the Title part of the dialog. 
Almost my project in the final stage, now there is a design issue that in the absence of Title the empty space looks odd. 
Can any one help me how to resolve the empty spacing in the dialog without title case?

Note: The close button position should not be changed. Since If I change the close button position for this case, It affects the entire dialog UI design.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your current position for the X is in the wrong position for the dialog, which is why it is looking odd. See how it is not so much of a problem just by changing its position slightly.

[image]

Also remember that this X is just a duplicate feature that does the same thing as an explicit Cancel button (the duplication is fine because many users expect this in the top-right of the dialog).

All I did was implement one of the Gestalt principles of visual perception - *[Proximity](http://graphicdesign.spokanefalls.edu/tutorials/process/gestaltprinciples/gestaltprinc.htm#proximity)*. In your image the X is closer to the text than the border of the dialog, which is why it was being perceived as belonging to the text. So all I did was ensure that the X is much closer to the corner of the dialog to ensure it is perceived as belong to the dialog rather than the text.

> Proximity occurs when elements are placed close together. They tend to be perceived as a group.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Please refer google gdrive "Rename" dialog, they too have given close button X closer to the text.

Comment: They might be one of the hottest corporations at the moment, but it doesn't guarantee they don't make mistakes.The Gestalt principles of visual perception are based on psychology, so maybe their designers weren't aware of this. Just because they didn't do this doesn't make them right.